# nonlinear map from one range to another

Tags: algorithm, math, range, equation

I have a maths problem I am somewhat stumped on.  I need to map a numbers from one range to another in a nonlinear fashion.  I have manually taken some sample data from what I am trying to achieve.  That looks as such.

source - desired result

0 - 1

78 - 0.885

363 - 0.625

1429 - 0.3

3404 - 0.155

7524 - 0.075

11604 - 0.05

The source number ranges from 0 to, ideally an infinite number, but happy if it stops somewhere in the 10s of thousands.  The resultant number is from 1 to 0.  It needs to drop off quickly then level off.  Ideally never reaching zero.

I am aware of the standard equation to map from one range to another.

```
y = ((x * origRange) / newRange) + newRangeOffset
```

Unfortunately this does not give me the desired results.  Is there a elegant nonlinear equation that would give me the results I am after?

Comment: this question probably belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: What are your _desired results_?

Comment: @perfectionist noted for next time, thanks.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel I have edited the post to state "desired results" rather than just "results".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f(x) = 620 / (620 + x)`
gives an answer accurate to within 2% of all your values

Comment: That work great thanks.  I am intrigued to know how you came with the number 620 though?

Comment: You wanted a function f(x) that tended toward 0 as x => infinity.  This suggested `f(x) = 1 / x.` A common way to transform this would be `f(x) = 1 / (x + c)`, but you also needed f(0) = 1, suggesting `f(x) = c / (x + c)`.  I'd like to say I did some clever calculus at this point, but really I opened excel and did some trial & error iteration.  Incidentally 617 is a better value for c.

Comment: A more rigorous of fitting data to the curve `f(x) = c/(x+c)` would be to rewrite it as `1/f(x) = 1 + x/c` - you can then use least-squares linear regression (which pretty much any software package can do, even Excel) to find the optimal value of `c`.  However, blindly fitting a curve to some data is very rarely a good idea - without knowing what the values represent, you are unable to tell what relationships would make sense (for example, this curve blows up at `x=-c`, and we have no way of knowing whether that is appropriate).

Comment: thanks for that.  Always good to learn the logic behind an answer.

Comment: @James Least squares regression would have taken a good minute or two more to do (i'd have to look up how to do it in Excel).  While you're right about the curve blowing up at x=-c, the questioner explicitly excluded negative values from the domain of the function.  The criteria for success were "match these values", "non negative domain", "asymptotic toward y=0 as x=> infinity"

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553868/an-equation-to-map-values-from-one-range-to-another), you can use a polynomial interpolation (present in multiple software packages).

If you want to try it, I suggest you to go to **Wolfram Alpha** and select the [Polynomial Interpolation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Polynomials.html).

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating%20polynomial%20%7B0,1%7D,%7B78,0.885%7D,%7B363,0.625%7D,%7B1429,0.3%7D) is one example using some of your points.